# Cannot assign string elements to NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I am trying to create an array of zeros and three-column types (integer, float, character).
[Reference question](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-75.php)

**Doubt**
Why `dtype=S` here is creating a binary String?

```
arr = np.zeros((3,), dtype=('i4,f4,S'))
arr

>>array([[(0, 0., b''), (0, 0., b''), (0, 0., b'')]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', 'S')])
```

**Issue**
Assignment of characters is not working, instead results in blank strings `b''`.

```
arr[:] = [(1, 2., 'A'),
               (2, 2., 'B'),
               (3, 3., 'C')]
arr

>>array([[(1, 2., b''), (2, 2., b''), (3, 3., b'')]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', 'S')])
```

**Doubt**
Why is problem solved by using `dtype='O'`, or `dtype='a40'` a python object?

```
x = np.zeros((3,), dtype=('i4,f4,O')) # same result goes with dtype='a40' 
new_data = [(1, 2., "A"), (2, 2., "B"), (3, 3., "C")]
x[:] = new_data
print(x)

>>[(1, 2., 'A') (2, 2., 'B') (3, 3., 'C')]
```

How `a40` is different from `S`, `O` and `U` `dtypes` for NumPy string elements?

Comment: Use something like 'S10'.  By itself 'S' is 'S0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `S` or `str` is understood to mean, 'a long enough string to hold the values':

```
In [389]: np.array('foobar', dtype='S')                                                        
Out[389]: array(b'foobar', dtype='|S6')
In [390]: np.array('foobar', dtype='str')                                                      
Out[390]: array('foobar', dtype='<U6')
```

But a compound dtype isn't one of them:

```
In [392]: np.array('foobar', dtype=[('x','S')])                                                
Out[392]: array((b'',), dtype=[('x', 'S')])
In [393]: np.array('foobar', dtype=[('x','S10')])                                              
Out[393]: array((b'foobar',), dtype=[('x', 'S10')])
```

'O' creates a different array - one with list like references to Python strings:

```
In [401]: np.array('foobar', 'O')                                                              
Out[401]: array('foobar', dtype=object)
In [405]: np.array('foobar', [('x','O')])                                                      
Out[405]: array(('foobar',), dtype=[('x', 'O')])
In [406]: np.array(b'foobar', [('x','O')])                                                     
Out[406]: array((b'foobar',), dtype=[('x', 'O')])
```